# Instance restart Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I do not know if I am in the right place, but I have hired a Google Cloud VM and it restarts practically every week and it cannot be. Is there a way to prevent the machine from restarting?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by two things:

1) Go to the VM-instance details page and check if Migrate VM-instance has been selected for host maintenance. Select this option if it's not, this should fix your problem (if the VM is not connected to a GPU).

2) According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions) instances with a GPU must terminate for host maintenance events and automatically restart. These maintenance events typically occur once per month but can occur more frequently.

You can receive advanced notice of host maintenance events by monitoring the /computeMetadata/v1/instance/maintenance-event metadata value. If this returns TERMINATE_ON_HOST_MAINTENANCE, you'll have one hour to prepare for the restart.